# What Is the Replacement for the @Decorator Directive?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-decorator

I'm upgrading my dart code from angular 1 to angular 4.

This line now gives an error in my IDE:

```
@Decorator(selector: '[citable]')
```

Annotation must either be a const variable or const construction invocation.

I was able to fix this error on @Input by including the formDirective. What directive should I use for @Decoration? I can't find any recent mention of @Decorator in a web search for AngularDart.

I tried adding const after selector:. Then I get a syntax error.

Comment: I worked with Angular 1 for a few months 2 years ago but can't remember what above code means. Angular 2 was a complete rewrite and hasn't much in common with Angular 1. I'd suggest ti start with the docs and tutorials in webdev.dartlang.org

Comment: I guess what you want is `@Directive()` or `@Component()` instead of `@Decorator()`

Answer (score 0):

The replacement is @Directive.